# CSS Grid - input not respecting padding

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm finding that when using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) that `inputs` are not respecting right side padding of their containing element. Specifically the `grid-template-colums` css attribute appears to be the culprit.

I found that this issue, CSS Grid Layout aside, was resolved through the application of `box-sizing: border-box`. Though even with that applied and a CSS reset I still appear to not be able to get around the issue.

Here is an abbreviated code snippet of the behavior from my React app:

http://www.webpackbin.com/VJ8DS5kOz

Here is an example of it with just vanilla HTML + CSS:

https://repl.it/F75i

I am also using [Styled Components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for styling in my React app which I'm fairly sure is not contributing to this behavior given that vanilla CSS test above.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think margin is what you want.  And I don't see that you've applied it to the input boxes.  I added the following line to the **CSS** file.  Does this do what you were looking for?

```
input { margin: 5px; }
```

Comment: I don't think margin is what I'm looking for here and when I added the above line I still got a bias to the left side in spacing to the inputs.

Comment: you could just add margin on the right side if that's all you're looking for.  margin-right: 5px;

Comment: some of my form elements span the full width and some only half. So the ones that span half would get extra wide gutters. I get CSS Grid is not fully fleshed out, so I suppose hacks may be necessary. Though aiming to find a more succinct and pattern appropriate way to resolve the issue so that I am not having to add special classes to each form element individually rather than just applying an attribute/s to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured something out, but, it seems like adding the [justify-content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

in the     form CSS does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles on this, the issue is if the input is a type that has a webkit appearance that's set by Chrome, this will override certain properties (like padding). You will need to set `-webkit-appearance: textfield;` on the input in order to be able to style it as expected.